# Не выводится .json файл в консоль

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Я только сегодня начал знакомиться с node.js и возникла проблема, я написал функцию, которая по идее должна выводить в консоль json в виде объекта, но нет

```
window.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded', () => {
    function req(){
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.open('GET', "http://localhost:3000/people")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "appication/json; charset=utf-8")
        request.send()
        request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
            if(request.readyState == 4){
                let data = JSON.parse(request.response)
                console.log(data)
            }
            else{
                console.error('Не получилось')
            }
        })
    }
    req()
})
```

Comment: Ну а хоть что-нибудь в консоли пишет? Где, когда и как запускается этот код?

Comment: ничего не вывелось, но если вы о том, что я неправильно подключил js то нет, когда пишешь alert(), то все видно

Comment: alert именно внутри функции req?

Comment: нет, сейчас попробую внутри

Comment: Нет, alert не работает

Comment: Значит, видимо, вопрос всё-таки имеет смысл - где, когда и как подключается/запускается этот код?

Comment: разве? сам файл запускается, я проверил в консоли соединения и есть запросы на сервер с кодом 200, поэтому проблема в самой функции

Comment: Значит добавьте `request.addEventListener('error'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто переписал скрипт, но уже без, того, чтобы ждать пока прогрузиться HTML, все работает наконец-то, если что, вот скрипт:

```
function dat(){
    function req(){
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/people")
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        request.send()
        request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                let data = JSON.parse(request.response)
                console.log(data)
            }
            else{
                console.error('что то пошло не так')
            }
        })
    }
    req()
}
dat()
```

Comment: Значит вопрос, где, когда и как подключается/запускается этот код, всё-таки имел смысл...